# Customize change_list.html in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

`change_list.html` has `Action` part where a user selects an action and applies it on the selected items(queryset).

What I am trying to do is the following:

```
1. Add an additional <select> box near Action select box
2. Add an additional action which will use the value of the added select box in step 1.
```

I tried to customize `change_list.html` but adding an additional select box seemed quite difficult.

Is it possible? How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to make a custom Admin Action?

If so, start with the [Django documentation for it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/actions/). Then Have a look at these two use cases:

- [Admin Action with parameters](http://agiliq.com/blog/2014/08/passing-parameters-to-django-admin-action/)
- [Admin Action with intermediate pages](http://www.jpichon.net/blog/2010/08/django-admin-actions-and-intermediate-pages/)

Comment: The first link was exactly what I needed. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

it is simple:

```
class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
        js = ('/static/js/adminfix.js', )

    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super(YourModelAdmin, self).get_urls()
        my_urls = patterns('',
            (r'^custom_action_select/$', self.custom_func)
        )
        return my_urls + urls

    def custom_func(self, request):
        # your action
```

and your adminfix.js would look like:

```
(function($) {
   $(document).ready(function($) {
      $(".object-tools").append('<select id="actionid">stuff</select>');
      $(".object-tools").on('click', '#actionid', function(e){
          // you send here the request to /custom_action_select/
          // and handle if in custom_func() in your admin.py 
      });
   });
})(django.jQuery);
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I wanted to make select box dynamic. Thanks anyway